# Is it possible to exit (return) from a switch case from a method in the same case.?

Tags: java

Is it possible to exit (return) from a switch case from a method in the same case?

Given this code:

```
switch(int blaah) {
    case 1: 
        some code here;
        break;
    case 2: 
        myMethod();
        some code here;
        break;
    default:
        some code here;
}

public void myMethod() {

    if(boolean condition) {
        return;  
        /*I want this return valuates in switch case too.
        so the switch case exit without executing the rest of code of "case 2" */

    }
        some code here;
}
```

I know the `return` here just skip the rest of the codes in `myMethod`. I am looking for something that tells the switch case to stop execution from the method.

Comment: The only "magic" way to do this is exception, and it's usually a really bad idea.

Comment: I think a better course of action here is you to explain what you want to do instead of **how** you want to do it. It is a clear case of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: you can change myMethod() signature to myMethod(boolean condition) and just pass it to the method when it is invoked.

Comment: Move the condition from the method to the call site? `if(boolean condition) myMethod()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to give a *meaningful* solution without the full context.

However...

You can return a boolean result from the method and based on it the switch case can decide to continue or not.

```
public boolean myMethod() {

    if(boolean condition) {
        return false;
    }
     //some code here;
     return true;
}


switch(int blaah) {
    case 1: 
        some code here;
        break;
    case 2: 
        if (myMethod()) {
            //some code here; //Execute only if the method signalled to do so
        }
        break;
    default:
        some code here;
}
```

Another option:

If `if(boolean condition)` is the first thing you do in the method, you can evaluate it in the switch case itself and can avoid calling the method if it turned out to be true and break immediately.

```
case 2: 
        if (boolean condition) {
            myMethod();
            //some code here;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Certainly an option - but this sort of thing quickly leads to very ugly code. You begin to use side-effects instead of return values so that you can return `boolean`, this quickly becomes spaghetti. Just a word of warning.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Completely agree.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have updated the answer with another option

Comment: I would stick with the first answer ( I do know the second option), damn I don't wanna mess my codes with it. 

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be

```
   case 2: 
        if (someCondition) {
            myMethod();
        }
         else {
          // some code
          }
        break;
```